# How to make a dependency optional in a package

Tags: r, dependencies, package

I am coding a package in R which – among other things – can show plots with rgl. However, I found out with my students that rgl is a hassle: especially with those who use Macs. I end up spending a lot of time helping them to install RGL.

Is there a proper, CRAN sanctioned way to make the package optionally dependent on rgl? That if rgl cannot be loaded, some functions send a warning message and exit gracefully? How best should I do it?

EDIT: I know how to actually do it in a function; however, what I don't know is how to formally define it in the package requirements such that (i) CRAN doesn't complain, but (ii) rgl is formally specified as an optional dependency.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `requireNamespace` in the definition of your functions that make use of `rgl`:

```
functionWithRgl<-function(...) {
   if (!requireNamespace("rgl", quietly = TRUE)) {
        warning("The rgl package must be installed to use this functionality")
        #Either exit or do something without rgl
        return(NULL)
    }
    #do stuff with rgl here prefixing it
    rgl::someRglFunction(someArguments)
    #...
}
```

In this way you don't need to declare `rgl` in the `Depends` or `Import` sections of the `Description` of your package.

Comment: Am I actually allowed to do that without specifying the dependency in DESCRIPTION? Will it pass the check --as.cran?

Comment: @January Your question (even your specific example) is covered by WRE: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Suggested-packages

Comment: Great, thank you. Turns out I didn't understand that bit.